# My custom query with @Query and Pageable works but doesn't return results

Tags: java, sql, spring-data-jpa

I have this query:

```
public interface IProductoDao extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Producto, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select * from productos p where p.nombre like %?1% and p.categoria = ?2",
            countQuery = "select count(*) from productos p where p.nombre like %?1% and p.categoria = ?2",
            nativeQuery = true)
    public Page<Producto> findByNombreAndCategoria(String term, String cat, Pageable pageable);
    
}
```

And works succesfully, but doesn't return results and I know that there are results in my database for this query.

If I print in console the Page object, I get next:

```
2021-04-03 23:40:59.963 DEBUG 19724 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select * from productos p where p.nombre like ? and p.categoria = ? limit ?
Productos: Page 1 of 0 containing UNKNOWN instances
```

I don't understand what the query is returning. I think the query should return something like this native method(findAll(Pageable page)) of PagingAndSortingRepository interface:

```
@Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Page<Producto> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        return productoDao.findAll(pageable);
    }
```

with this result:

```
2021-04-03 23:49:01.506 DEBUG 19724 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select producto0_.id as id1_0_, producto0_.categoria as categori2_0_, producto0_.descripcion as descripc3_0_, producto0_.imagenes as imagenes4_0_, producto0_.nombre as nombre5_0_, producto0_.precio as precio6_0_ from productos producto0_ limit ?
2021-04-03 23:49:01.509 DEBUG 19724 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select count(producto0_.id) as col_0_0_ from productos producto0_
Productos: Page 1 of 6 containing com.abril.tiendaonline.app.models.entity.Producto instances
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Are you sure that [advanced like expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query.advanced-like) work with native queries?

Comment: Yes because when doesn't work throws an error.